# Javascript for loop keeps crashing even with low number of iterations

Tags: javascript

The code below is used to generate a random word.

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function randomWord(length=6){
    string = '';
    vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"];  
    consonants = [
        'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
        'n', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
    ];  

    max = length / 2;
    for (i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        string += consonants[randomInteger(0,19)];
        string += vowels[randomInteger(0,4)];
    }
    return string;
}
```

Based on this, I am using the following function to create a sentence.

```
function randomSentence(tot=10){
    returner = '';
    for(j=0;j<tot;j++){
        returner = returner + " " + randomWord();
    }
    return returner;
}

postContent = [];
for(a=0;a<10;a++){
    postContent.push(randomSentence(5));
}
```

The value of `i<10` is what causes the program to crash, it seems to work when the value is set to `5`.

Comment: Always (and I mean "always") declare your variables, with `let` or `const` or `var` to scope them appropriately. Otherwise they are global, and lead to weird _bugs_ like the one you're having. You're using the same `i` in different loops. **Edit** Well, now you edited your question to use `a` in the second loop, but still, you should really do it

Comment: @blex My bad, that fixed it! Thank you

Comment: What error do you get when it crashes?